# Cannot switch from Intel to Nvidia graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have an Hp ab555-tx laptop with Nvidia G940m graphics along with Intel HD graphics. The system by default chooses the Intel graphics but I want to switch to the Nvidia one, which I am unable to do. **Any help with switching to the Nvidia gpu would be highly appreciated.**

Some useful info:

Running `nvidia-smi` gives the following output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa88z.png)

Running `nvidia-settings` gives the following output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv6Su.png)

**UPDATE: Removing linux lite 5.8 and installing ubuntu 22.04 solved the problem.**

---

@helloubuntu
`sudo prime-select nvidia` returns `sudo: prime-select: command not found`. Installing nvidia-prime through shows this error

`abhra@abhra-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: fd-find gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-raise-first-window gnome-shell-extension-always-show-workspaces gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-pop-shop-details pop-gnome-shell-theme pop-gtk-theme pop-icon-theme pop-shell pop-shell-shortcuts pop-sound-theme pop-theme xwayland Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The following packages will be REMOVED: gnome-shell-extension-system76-power pop-default-settings pop-session pop-shell-plugin-system76-power system76-power The following NEW packages will be installed: nvidia-prime 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/9,960 B of archives. After this operation, 2,915 kB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 435632 files and directories currently installed.) Removing pop-default-settings (4.0.6~1611854075~20.04~6a2277e) ... Removing 'diversion of /etc/lsb-release to /etc/lsb-release.diverted by pop-default-settings' dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/etc/lsb-release' with different file '/etc/lsb-release.diverted', not allowed dpkg: error processing package pop-default-settings (--remove): installed pop-default-settings package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2 dpkg: too many errors, stopping Errors were encountered while processing: pop-default-settings Processing was halted because there were too many errors. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, I have linux lite 5.8 installed and Secure Boot is disabled in the BIOS and greyed out, I don't know if I can enable it

Comment: Unfortunately we can't support Linux Lite here. This is a Ubuntu support site. But do see the answer shown below.

Comment: @heynnema I have installed ubuntu 22.04 now and it is working well, I got rid of linux lite. Thanks, it kinda sorted my issue haha

Comment: Since your issue was with linux lite, this question is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

to switch back to intel

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

to check which card is selected at the moment

```
prime-select query
```